# How to return desired manual value based on specific parameters in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL query in SQL Server 2008 like this:

```
declare @Waited6_8 varchar(max) = 'true'
declare @Waited8_12 varchar(max) = 'false'
declare @Waited12_18 varchar(max) = 'true'

Select 
    choice = case when @Waited6_8 = 'true' then '6-8'
                  when @Waited8_12 = 'true' then '8-12'
                  when @Waited12_18 = 'true' then '12-18' 
             end
```

Here, I get `6-8` as the result.

What I would like to see is: `6-8, 12-18` as one string (not as different rows)

How can I get this? I appreciate if you help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @Waited6_8 varchar(max) = 'true'
declare @Waited8_12 varchar(max) = 'false'
declare @Waited12_18 varchar(max) = 'true'


Select choice = isnull(case when @Waited6_8 = 'true' then '6-8' end + ', ','') +
                isnull(case when @Waited8_12 = 'true' then '8-12' end + ', ','') +
                isnull(case when @Waited12_18 = 'true' then '12-18' end,'')
```

Comment: For `@Waited6_8 = 'true'`, `@Waited8_12 = 'false'`, `@Waited12_18 = 'false'`, it will give `6-8, `

Answer (score 0):

The query you write, it is like `if-else if` statement that's why you get one value (`6-8 here`). You can get your desired result by using this query.

```
Select choice = (case when @Waited6_8 = 'true' then '6-8' else '' end) +
 (case when @Waited6_8 = 'true' and @Waited8_12 = 'true' then ', ' else '' end) +
 (case when @Waited8_12 = 'true' then '8-12' else '' end) +
 (case when (@Waited6_8 = 'true' or @Waited8_12 = 'true') and @Waited12_18 = 'true' then ', ' else '' end) +
 (case when @Waited12_18 = 'true' then '12-18' else '' end)
```

Comment: OP expected comma separated values

Comment: I just try to show him, how he can get two values, btw i update the answer.

Comment: Now your query returns `8-12, ` extra comma  in the end for the `@Waited8_12 = true`, `@Waited6_8 = false` and `@Waited12_18 = false`

Comment: Yeah, now it will give the correct result. but the logic too complex.

Comment: The logic is bit complex but correct one whereas accepted answer will give wrong answer for `true, false, false`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be better served with a few IF blocks.

```
DECLARE @Waited6_8 varchar(max) = 'true',
        @Waited8_12 varchar(max) = 'false',
        @Waited12_18 varchar(max) = 'true',
        @Choice VARCHAR(MAX)

IF (@Waited6_8 = 'true')
BEGIN
     SET @Choice += '6-8 ';
END
IF (@Waited8_12 = 'true')
BEGIN
     SET @Choice += '8-12 ';
END
IF (Waited12_18 = 'true')
BEGIN
     SET @Choice += '12-18';
END

PRINT RTRIM(@Choice);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have taken Case you can do it by performing just concatenation like,

```
declare @Waited6_8 varchar(max) = 'true'
declare @Waited8_12 varchar(max) = 'false'
declare @Waited12_18 varchar(max) = 'true'    

Select choice = isnull(case when @Waited6_8 = 'true' then '6-8' end + ', ','') +
                isnull(case when @Waited8_12 = 'true' then '8-12' end + ',   ','') + //This case will get omitted as it contains null value
                isnull(case when @Waited12_18 = 'true' then '12-18' end,'')
```

Check output,
[image]

Please refer working fiddle,http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/8083, I have created this example regarding your question.this might solve all your questions.

Here It concats all 3 case,but omitting NULL value case so you will not get value of middle case.

Please note, make sure you put **ISNULL** before each case else it will also show you null value of middle case.

Comment: For `@Waited6_8 = 'true'`, `@Waited8_12 = 'false'`, `@Waited12_18 = 'false'`, it will give `6-8, `